# How do I access /cygdrive/c/.. in a bash script?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

Why can't the folder be found? I double checked that it exists.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This will sync the background_docs folder"
lftp ftp://user:pass@server.org -e "mirror -r /cygdrive/c/Users/usera/Desktop/test_folder/ --only-missing -e;exit"
```

Comment: Are you trying to access `/cygdrive/c` or `/cygdrive/C`?

Comment: You want to put that in a answer? I totally noobed it. I should have saw that. that's the only command that failed out of 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could that be your problem: "mirror - Mirror specified source directory to local target directory" If I read that correctly then you are looking for the /cygdrive/c/.... dir on the FTP server which probably does not have a cygwin-based FTP server. Try -R if you want to put files to the server, or write "mirror -r server-dir /cygdrive/c/..." – HelmuthB

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at cygpath

cygpath -w

```
converts to windows path
```

cygpath -u

```
converts to unix path
```